# VSTS Hosted Linux Preview with Karma and ChromeHeadless

Tags: angular, azure-devops, karma-runner, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

My stack is as follows: Angular 6, Karma, [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) with ChromeHeadless. I am trying to set-up a CI build on [VSTS Hosted Linux Preview](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/blob/master/ubuntu/16.04/standard/Dockerfile). However when I run my unit tests on the build machine I get the following error.

> Cannot start ChromeHeadless   /opt/vsts/work/1/s/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-555668/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If I switch to the [Hosted VS2017](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) build then it works fine. That's probably because it comes with Chrome pre-installed. I've tried to install Chrome to the Linux build machine but still no luck. Unfortunately for this particular build I need to use the Linux box so I can't switch to the Windows Hosted VS2017 box.

My karma.conf.js file looks as follows:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeNoSandbox: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless'],
    },
  },
  singleRun: true,
 });
};
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you check this issue? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2013

Comment: What's the result if you install necessary packages before testing? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Shell script task:

Script:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -qq -y install libpangocairo-1.0-0 libx11-xcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxi6 libxtst6 libnss3 libcups2 libxss1 libxrandr2 libgconf2-4 libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libgtk-3-0
```

Comment: Does not work:
`2018-05-31T15:00:03.3240335Z [command]/bin/bash /opt/vsts/work/1/s/bin/install-libXss.sh
2018-05-31T15:00:04.8262892Z E: Invalid operation update
2018-05-31T15:00:05.3121461Z E: Unable to locate package libxss1
2018-05-31T15:00:05.3276423Z E: Unable to locate package libgconf2-4
2018-05-31T15:00:05.3430559Z E: Unable to locate package libgtk-3-0`